# Multiple Input State Table method

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vhdl, state-machine

I am a novice in VHDL. In one of my assignments I needed to implement a state machine in a State Table method using VHDL. So i wrote the following code for the architechture entity :

X,Y are input bits basically this is a moore machine which accepts two inputs and outputs a bit.

```
   architecture Table of SM1_2 is
  type StateTable is array(integer range<>,bit range<>,bit range<>) of integer;
  type OutTable is array(integer range<>) of bit;
  signal State,NextState : integer := 0;
  constant ST: StateTable(0 to 3,'0' to '1','0' to '1'):=
    ((3,0,1,0),(2,0,1,1),(3,0,1,1),(2,0,1,0));
  constant OT: OutTable(0 to 3):=
  ('0','1','1','0');
begin                               --Concurrent Statements
  NextState <= ST(State,X,Y);       --Next state from state table
  Z <= OT(State);
```

ModelSim reports an error: `Integer literal 3 is not of type sub-array #3 of StateTable.`

I have googled extensively and am not able to find a solution for this. How do I use multidimensional arrays in VHDL?

Comment: My guess would be that either X or Y are integers not bits, but without the rest of the declarations or a hint which line contains the error we can only take shots in the dark. Simplify your source as far as you can while still showing the error, and post that.

Comment: Just edited. @BrianDrummond can you take a look?

Comment: NextState should not be initialized, it's not a register.

Comment: @Paebbels could you tell me why? also where have i initialized it?

Comment: The signal `State` is mapped to a register, which can have a initial value and a reset value on most platforms. The signal/wire `NextState` is a combinatorical signal. These signals can not have a initial value in real hardware. Your statement `signal State,NextState : integer := 0;` assigns the value 0 to NextState, but not to State, so swap the names or use one line per signal name. Not defaulting pure wires is also better for simulation: now it's possible to see unconnected signals because they are initialized with 'U'. Rule of thumb: only signals which map to registers have default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StateTable` type is declared as multi-dimentional array of `integer` type:

```
type StateTable is array(integer range<>,bit range<>,bit range<>) of integer;
```

The the constant created from this type is assigned with an array that does not have the required levels in:

```
constant ST : StateTable(0 to 3,'0' to '1','0' to '1') := ( (3,0,1,0), ...
```

So try adding levels in the constant value, like:

```
constant ST: StateTable(0 to 3,'0' to '1','0' to '1'):=
  (((3, 0), (1, 0)), 
   ((2, 0), (1, 1)), 
   ((3, 0), (1, 1)), 
   ((2, 0), (1, 0)));
```

The index value may be used when creating the constant, to make it clearer what values are assigned to different elements in the array:

```
constant ST: StateTable(0 to 3,'0' to '1','0' to '1'):=
  (0 => ('0' => ('0' => 3, '1' => 0),
         '1' => ('0' => 1, '1' => 0)),
   1 => ('0' => ('0' => 2, '1' => 0),
         '1' => ('0' => 1, '1' => 1)),
   2 => ('0' => ('0' => 3, '1' => 0),
         '1' => ('0' => 1, '1' => 1)),
   3 => ('0' => ('0' => 2, '1' => 0),
         '1' => ('0' => 1, '1' => 0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nested arrays to build a state table:

```
constant state_cnt : positive := 4;
type t_inputtable is array (bit range <>, bit range <>) of natural range 0 to state_cnt-1;
type_t_statetable is array (natural range 0 to state_cnt-1) of t_inputtable;

constant statetable is t_statetable := (
--state   X,   Y   next state
  0 => (('0', '0') => 0,
        ('0', '1') => 1,
        ('1', '0') => 2,
        others => 0),
  1 => (('0', '0') => 0,
        ('0', '1') => 3,
        ('1', '0') => 2,
        others => 1),
  -- ...
  );

 nextState <= statetable(State)(X, Y);
```

I hope I made no mistake in typing this lines.
You can also implement a outputrecord:

```
type t_outputtable is record
  next : natural range 0 to state_cnt-1;
  O1 : bit;
  O2 : bit;
end record;
type t_inputtable is array (bit range <>, bit range <>) of t_outputtable;
type_t_statetable is array (natural range 0 to state_cnt-1) of t_inputtable;

nextState <= statetable(State)(X, Y).next;
Output1 <= statetable(State)(X, Y).O1;
```